# Iterative Algorithm for increasing matrix rank

Tags: matrices, algorithms, matrix-rank

I have a random $N$ by $M$ matrix W where $N > M$. I am looking for an algorithm that would iteratively update the elements of a matrix so that eventually the matrix has full rank and preferably a good condition number. Additionally, it would be great if the algorithm was iterative, making infinitesimal steps of the form

$W_{ij}(t+1)= W_{ij}(t) + V_{ij} \Delta t$

where $\Delta t$ can be arbitrary small. What are my options

**Edit 1:** Here is a naive algorithm which outlines why I believe the problem might be solvable. Consider a matrix $U$ which has the same shape as $W$, except it is full rank. Then the iterative process

$$W(t+1) = U\Delta t + W(t) (1-\Delta t)$$

will converge to $W = U$, so it will generate a full-rank matrix. The reason I don't like this solution is because I don't want the matrix to converge to some pre-determined matrix, but instead to some matrix "nearby", whichever way it is defined

**Edit 2**: Ok, so apparently adding random numbers is good enough. I have considered a random iterative procedure

$$W_{ij}(t+1)= W_{ij}(t) + R_{ij}(t) \Delta t$$

where $R(t)$ is a matrix of random normal numbers of mean 0 and variance 1, updated at every time step. I have set $\Delta t = 0.01$, $(N,M) = (20, 10)$ and initialized $W$ with ones, so that its rank initially is 1. Then I simulated rank and condition number of $W$, as well as eigenvalues of $W^T W$. Here's what I got

[image: Rank and Condition number]

[image: Eigenvalues]

Answer (score 1):

Sadly, your search is hopeless. Consider
$$
\pmatrix{1 & 0 \\ 0 & 0}
$$
which has rank $1$. Perturb it a tiny bit to 
$$
\pmatrix{1+a & b \\ c & d}
$$
and look at the resulting eigenvalues. The determinant (product of eigenvalues!) is $(1+a)d - bc$, which is very nearly $d \approx 0$; the trace (sum of eigenvalues!) is $1+a + d$, which is very nearly $1$. So one of the eigenvalues must be nearly $1$, and hence the other must be approximately $d$, so the condition number is approximately $1/|d|$, which is huge.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I'm not sure I agree. If I have a rank-1 matrix and I apply a small perturbation to it, naturally the 2nd eigenvalue would be small. But what about applying many perturbations?

Comment: can't he go with normalization to fix the condition number (adding a little bit of the identity matrix)?

Comment: Sure, you can apply many perturbations. I was assuming you wanted to find a matrix *close* to the original, and use a small number of perturbations relative to the size of the matrix. As you've since observed, bad matrices are (relatively) sparse in the set of all matrices, so a random walk in the space of matrices will get you away from the bad ones...of course, it'll also take you away from your starting matrix. Then again, if you're willing to do that, you could just replace your starting matrix with the identity, and do it in $O(1)$ time. :(

Comment: @JohnHughes, I agree with what you've said. It would be a tradeoff between ending up with a different matrix or an unstable matrix no matter what. Another idea I had might be to just iteratively apply rank-one updates using the Sherman-Morrison formula, so that the matrix modifications are a little less than random.

Comment: Yeah, the problem is that I don't really know what the question is :D. I'm trying to guess how a certain neuronal network works in a real brain, but the problem is seriously underconstrained due to lack of experimental evidence. The actual question is how a set of synaptic connections between two neuronal population succeeds at avoiding excessive degeneracy. The question is not well-understood, but it seems that random fluctuations of synaptic weights are a positive thing.